# Browsers become unresponsive due to a long running script - How can I find the script responsible?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, aurelia

I'm currently facing a peculiar problem. In our QA environment we found that a specific entity is causing browsers to become unresponsive. It is a quite large Aurelia project so even if I have the entity causing the page to be unresponsive there are several thousand lines of JavaScript that I would have to debug to find out why this is happening. To make matters worse we are also using `expressionObserver` on `BindingEngine` to detect when properties are changing and other event based functionality. This means that following a synchronous flow is therefore not that easy either.

I have tried running Chrome Performance but the profiler lags out.

[image]

Is there some way that I can target the specific code causing the lag or do I have to step through the code line by line?

Chrome:

[image]

Page Unresponsive
You can wait for it to become responsive or exit the page.

Firefox:

[image]

A web page is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do?

Edge:

[image]

is not responding.

Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

is not responding due to a long-running script.

Comment: Running a Performance test with Devtools might expose the long polling function ..?

Comment: Start with checking loops (esp while loops ) that they can reach their exit condition. Also check if you use getElementsByClassName or getElementsByTagName anywhere, since another common thing is forgetting they return live lists, so adding nodes to the list inside the loop will loop over those nodes as well. And lastly, all ajax that repeats if the http call fails to resolve. Those are the 3 most common infinite loops I find.

Comment: @Teemu Tried that but the profiler lags out unfortunately as stated above.

Comment: It is not recovered when you stop the script?

Comment: @Teemu unfortunately not. I could try to find a third party tool that works.

Comment: It looks like the profiler would work in FF despite of an infinite loop. If you profiled [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgk2xszm/) using FF, you can see the name of the hanging function after stopping the script, in the profiler.

Comment: If you can locate the relevant html/ JS, posting here may help

Comment: @Teemu This fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Performance` monitor in `FireFox` it was possible to stop script execution and look at the methods executing before the application became unresponsive. Thanks to @Teemu.

[image]